# How to solve this react native error execute project react native?

Tags: react-native, package, project, execute

[enter image description here][1]

this my error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDILQ.png

Answer (score 0):

You must update your react native version or update this package because the version of this package is not adequate with react native version.